# Rendering vectors in a sphere, with better perception

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I need to render some 3D vectors starting in (0,0,0) ending all on a sphere. Currently I do this with python and matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("equal")

# render the sphere mesh
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 00:np.pi:10j]
x=np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y=np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z=np.cos(v)
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color="r")
plt.axis('off')

class Arrow3D(FancyArrowPatch):
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, zs, *args, **kwargs):
        FancyArrowPatch.__init__(self, (0,0), (0,0), *args, **kwargs)
        self._verts3d = xs, ys, zs

    def draw(self, renderer):
        xs3d, ys3d, zs3d = self._verts3d
        xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
        self.set_positions((xs[0],ys[0]),(xs[1],ys[1]))
        FancyArrowPatch.draw(self, renderer)

gradients = [[ 0.57735027, -0.57735027,  0.57735027], [ 0.32103634, -0.15367924, -0.93451506], [ 0.41923004, -0.40336058,  0.81335509], [ 0.49175236, -0.7972576 , -0.35008559], [-0.77544582, -0.60942662,  0.16517574], [ 0.49080035, -0.37864643, -0.78469223], [-0.9688558 , -0.14921457, -0.19761968], [-0.55381966, -0.41340241, -0.72276008], [-0.51651138, -0.82581121,  0.22638878], [ 0.51285124, -0.09350922,  0.85336959], [-0.02404559, -0.99431705, -0.10370783], [-0.45752126, -0.15967038,  0.87474549], [-0.11906644, -0.66461051,  0.73764223], [-0.69553846, -0.26904184,  0.66621518], [ 0.84464198, -0.38759068,  0.3692607 ], [ 0.01218729, -0.86413401,  0.5031141 ], [-0.70542359, -0.10816363, -0.70048422], [-0.64579558, -0.75719821, -0.09797404], [ 0.22307518, -0.66173422,  0.715783  ], [ 0.35672677, -0.81123132,  0.46330312], [-0.64859039, -0.59819001,  0.47063699], [-0.9860335 , -0.04110239,  0.16139577], [ 0.78665483, -0.298026  , -0.54069835], [-0.22515292, -0.39356178,  0.89129978], [-0.03115982, -0.20828982, -0.97757065], [ 0.1714755 , -0.88971114, -0.42309603], [-0.1948448 , -0.48424336, -0.85296184], [-0.46394941, -0.51801461,  0.71861798], [-0.45273268, -0.81954175, -0.35126126], [-0.82887799, -0.29984823, -0.47228414], [ 0.21121763, -0.09845807,  0.97246754], [-0.11702234, -0.10076906,  0.98800373], [ 0.31119478, -0.68396461, -0.65981078], [ 0.65285712, -0.07680383, -0.75357729], [ 0.71209121, -0.26699486,  0.64933801], [ 0.97685069, -0.17835225,  0.11812361], [-0.34381351, -0.93718553, -0.05895334], [ 0.68615079, -0.67022949,  0.2828241 ], [-0.6588605 , -0.59295917, -0.46292791], [ 0.15754543, -0.46902952, -0.86901712], [ 0.89081973, -0.0551779 ,  0.45099396], [ 0.09939465, -0.40802586,  0.90754372], [ 0.93604255, -0.26702261, -0.22917943], [-0.93707269, -0.34256476,  0.06741077], [-0.19623031, -0.95031369,  0.24165596], [ 0.45153776, -0.87650371,  0.16689767], [-0.0195914 , -0.72917062, -0.68405145], [ 0.65216494, -0.75583613, -0.05824633], [ 0.13336134, -0.97014433,  0.20257032], [ 0.86954373, -0.49204889,  0.04220884], [ 0.60317737, -0.57162017, -0.55626202], [-0.34353963, -0.78447777,  0.51630914], [-0.35424244, -0.68266952, -0.63912022], [-0.84101379, -0.50332689, -0.19838808], [-0.85885382, -0.33475134,  0.38770047], [ 0.30507854, -0.94518369, -0.11642545], [ 0.7822451 , -0.55481136, -0.28333196], [-0.15034926, -0.90096235, -0.4070158 ], [-0.37529847, -0.20644124, -0.90362221], [-0.87414831, -0.01486413,  0.48543158]]

for i in gradients:
    ax.add_artist( Arrow3D([0,-i[0]],[0,-i[1]],[0,-i[2]], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="k") )
    ax.add_artist( Arrow3D([0,i[0]],[0,i[1]],[0,i[2]], mutation_scale=20, lw=1, arrowstyle="-|>", color="k") )
plt.show()
```

Which results in such images:

[image]

However, this is very bad, as no spatial depth is visible. How can I improve the result?

**Edit**:
Their endings have no special meaning, but the reader of the image should see, that these directions are almost uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The apparent lack of depth in your current rendering is mostly due to the lack of shading.

`matplotlib` isn't set up to handle "true" 3D rendering (i.e. occlusion, shading, etc), and you're going to need a lot of the subtle visual hints that this gives to get the impression of depth.

`mayavi.mlab` is a good choice for a simple python API to a very full-featured 3D visualization package (VTK).

As an example based on yours:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

# render the sphere mesh
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 00:np.pi:10j]
x=np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y=np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z=np.cos(v)

for a,b,c in zip(x.T, y.T, z.T) + zip(x, y, z):
    mlab.plot3d(a, b, c, color=(1,0,0), tube_radius=0.01)

gradients = np.array([[ 0.57735027, -0.57735027,  0.57735027], [ 0.32103634, -0.15367924, -0.93451506], [ 0.41923004, -0.40336058,  0.81335509], [ 0.49175236, -0.7972576 , -0.35008559], [-0.77544582, -0.60942662,  0.16517574], [ 0.49080035, -0.37864643, -0.78469223], [-0.9688558 , -0.14921457, -0.19761968], [-0.55381966, -0.41340241, -0.72276008], [-0.51651138, -0.82581121,  0.22638878], [ 0.51285124, -0.09350922,  0.85336959], [-0.02404559, -0.99431705, -0.10370783], [-0.45752126, -0.15967038,  0.87474549], [-0.11906644, -0.66461051,  0.73764223], [-0.69553846, -0.26904184,  0.66621518], [ 0.84464198, -0.38759068,  0.3692607 ], [ 0.01218729, -0.86413401,  0.5031141 ], [-0.70542359, -0.10816363, -0.70048422], [-0.64579558, -0.75719821, -0.09797404], [ 0.22307518, -0.66173422,  0.715783  ], [ 0.35672677, -0.81123132,  0.46330312], [-0.64859039, -0.59819001,  0.47063699], [-0.9860335 , -0.04110239,  0.16139577], [ 0.78665483, -0.298026  , -0.54069835], [-0.22515292, -0.39356178,  0.89129978], [-0.03115982, -0.20828982, -0.97757065], [ 0.1714755 , -0.88971114, -0.42309603], [-0.1948448 , -0.48424336, -0.85296184], [-0.46394941, -0.51801461,  0.71861798], [-0.45273268, -0.81954175, -0.35126126], [-0.82887799, -0.29984823, -0.47228414], [ 0.21121763, -0.09845807,  0.97246754], [-0.11702234, -0.10076906,  0.98800373], [ 0.31119478, -0.68396461, -0.65981078], [ 0.65285712, -0.07680383, -0.75357729], [ 0.71209121, -0.26699486,  0.64933801], [ 0.97685069, -0.17835225,  0.11812361], [-0.34381351, -0.93718553, -0.05895334], [ 0.68615079, -0.67022949,  0.2828241 ], [-0.6588605 , -0.59295917, -0.46292791], [ 0.15754543, -0.46902952, -0.86901712], [ 0.89081973, -0.0551779 ,  0.45099396], [ 0.09939465, -0.40802586,  0.90754372], [ 0.93604255, -0.26702261, -0.22917943], [-0.93707269, -0.34256476,  0.06741077], [-0.19623031, -0.95031369,  0.24165596], [ 0.45153776, -0.87650371,  0.16689767], [-0.0195914 , -0.72917062, -0.68405145], [ 0.65216494, -0.75583613, -0.05824633], [ 0.13336134, -0.97014433,  0.20257032], [ 0.86954373, -0.49204889,  0.04220884], [ 0.60317737, -0.57162017, -0.55626202], [-0.34353963, -0.78447777,  0.51630914], [-0.35424244, -0.68266952, -0.63912022], [-0.84101379, -0.50332689, -0.19838808], [-0.85885382, -0.33475134,  0.38770047], [ 0.30507854, -0.94518369, -0.11642545], [ 0.7822451 , -0.55481136, -0.28333196], [-0.15034926, -0.90096235, -0.4070158 ], [-0.37529847, -0.20644124, -0.90362221], [-0.87414831, -0.01486413,  0.48543158]])
u, v, w = gradients.T
zero = np.zeros_like(u)

kwargs = dict(color=(.2,.2,.2), mode='arrow', resolution=20)
mlab.quiver3d(zero, zero, zero, u, v, w, **kwargs)
mlab.quiver3d(zero, zero, zero, -u, -v, -w, **kwargs)

mlab.show()
```

[image]

The only downside to this is that the relative arrow heads are fixed (they're just a static glyph).  It's probably possible to change that (i.e. use a custom glyph), but I don't know how offhand.

You can work around that by drawing the arrow head and body separately. This will be slow to render, but it illustrates the idea:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

# render the sphere mesh
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 00:np.pi:10j]
x=np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y=np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z=np.cos(v)

# White background and turn on antialiasing
fig = mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1,1,1))
fig.scene.render_window.aa_frames = 8

# Plot the sphere's mesh
for a,b,c in zip(x.T, y.T, z.T) + zip(x, y, z):
    mlab.plot3d(a, b, c, color=(1,0,0), tube_radius=0.01)

gradients = np.array([[ 0.57735027, -0.57735027,  0.57735027], [ 0.32103634, -0.15367924, -0.93451506], [ 0.41923004, -0.40336058,  0.81335509], [ 0.49175236, -0.7972576 , -0.35008559], [-0.77544582, -0.60942662,  0.16517574], [ 0.49080035, -0.37864643, -0.78469223], [-0.9688558 , -0.14921457, -0.19761968], [-0.55381966, -0.41340241, -0.72276008], [-0.51651138, -0.82581121,  0.22638878], [ 0.51285124, -0.09350922,  0.85336959], [-0.02404559, -0.99431705, -0.10370783], [-0.45752126, -0.15967038,  0.87474549], [-0.11906644, -0.66461051,  0.73764223], [-0.69553846, -0.26904184,  0.66621518], [ 0.84464198, -0.38759068,  0.3692607 ], [ 0.01218729, -0.86413401,  0.5031141 ], [-0.70542359, -0.10816363, -0.70048422], [-0.64579558, -0.75719821, -0.09797404], [ 0.22307518, -0.66173422,  0.715783  ], [ 0.35672677, -0.81123132,  0.46330312], [-0.64859039, -0.59819001,  0.47063699], [-0.9860335 , -0.04110239,  0.16139577], [ 0.78665483, -0.298026  , -0.54069835], [-0.22515292, -0.39356178,  0.89129978], [-0.03115982, -0.20828982, -0.97757065], [ 0.1714755 , -0.88971114, -0.42309603], [-0.1948448 , -0.48424336, -0.85296184], [-0.46394941, -0.51801461,  0.71861798], [-0.45273268, -0.81954175, -0.35126126], [-0.82887799, -0.29984823, -0.47228414], [ 0.21121763, -0.09845807,  0.97246754], [-0.11702234, -0.10076906,  0.98800373], [ 0.31119478, -0.68396461, -0.65981078], [ 0.65285712, -0.07680383, -0.75357729], [ 0.71209121, -0.26699486,  0.64933801], [ 0.97685069, -0.17835225,  0.11812361], [-0.34381351, -0.93718553, -0.05895334], [ 0.68615079, -0.67022949,  0.2828241 ], [-0.6588605 , -0.59295917, -0.46292791], [ 0.15754543, -0.46902952, -0.86901712], [ 0.89081973, -0.0551779 ,  0.45099396], [ 0.09939465, -0.40802586,  0.90754372], [ 0.93604255, -0.26702261, -0.22917943], [-0.93707269, -0.34256476,  0.06741077], [-0.19623031, -0.95031369,  0.24165596], [ 0.45153776, -0.87650371,  0.16689767], [-0.0195914 , -0.72917062, -0.68405145], [ 0.65216494, -0.75583613, -0.05824633], [ 0.13336134, -0.97014433,  0.20257032], [ 0.86954373, -0.49204889,  0.04220884], [ 0.60317737, -0.57162017, -0.55626202], [-0.34353963, -0.78447777,  0.51630914], [-0.35424244, -0.68266952, -0.63912022], [-0.84101379, -0.50332689, -0.19838808], [-0.85885382, -0.33475134,  0.38770047], [ 0.30507854, -0.94518369, -0.11642545], [ 0.7822451 , -0.55481136, -0.28333196], [-0.15034926, -0.90096235, -0.4070158 ], [-0.37529847, -0.20644124, -0.90362221], [-0.87414831, -0.01486413,  0.48543158]])
u, v, w = gradients.T
zero = np.zeros_like(u)

color = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
head_length = 0.2
for direct in [-1, 1]:
    h, b = direct * 0.2, direct * (1 - head_length)
    mlab.quiver3d(b*u, b*v, b*w, h*u, h*v, h*w, 
                  mode='cone', scale_factor=1, color=color, resolution=20)
    for i, j, k in zip(u, v, w):
        mlab.plot3d([0, b*i], [0, b*j], [0, b*k], color=color, tube_radius=0.01)

mlab.show()
```

[image]

You could also change things so that the cones are on the outside of the sphere:

[image]

Taking that one step farther, you can improve the rendering speed a bit and get a less confusing figure by doing:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

# White background and turn on antialiasing
fig = mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1,1,1))
fig.scene.render_window.aa_frames = 8

# Sphere at origin with a diameter of 2 (radius of 1)
ltgray = (0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
mlab.points3d([0], [0], [0], [2], resolution=20, scale_factor=1, color=ltgray)

gradients = np.array([[ 0.57735027, -0.57735027,  0.57735027], [ 0.32103634, -0.15367924, -0.93451506], [ 0.41923004, -0.40336058,  0.81335509], [ 0.49175236, -0.7972576 , -0.35008559], [-0.77544582, -0.60942662,  0.16517574], [ 0.49080035, -0.37864643, -0.78469223], [-0.9688558 , -0.14921457, -0.19761968], [-0.55381966, -0.41340241, -0.72276008], [-0.51651138, -0.82581121,  0.22638878], [ 0.51285124, -0.09350922,  0.85336959], [-0.02404559, -0.99431705, -0.10370783], [-0.45752126, -0.15967038,  0.87474549], [-0.11906644, -0.66461051,  0.73764223], [-0.69553846, -0.26904184,  0.66621518], [ 0.84464198, -0.38759068,  0.3692607 ], [ 0.01218729, -0.86413401,  0.5031141 ], [-0.70542359, -0.10816363, -0.70048422], [-0.64579558, -0.75719821, -0.09797404], [ 0.22307518, -0.66173422,  0.715783  ], [ 0.35672677, -0.81123132,  0.46330312], [-0.64859039, -0.59819001,  0.47063699], [-0.9860335 , -0.04110239,  0.16139577], [ 0.78665483, -0.298026  , -0.54069835], [-0.22515292, -0.39356178,  0.89129978], [-0.03115982, -0.20828982, -0.97757065], [ 0.1714755 , -0.88971114, -0.42309603], [-0.1948448 , -0.48424336, -0.85296184], [-0.46394941, -0.51801461,  0.71861798], [-0.45273268, -0.81954175, -0.35126126], [-0.82887799, -0.29984823, -0.47228414], [ 0.21121763, -0.09845807,  0.97246754], [-0.11702234, -0.10076906,  0.98800373], [ 0.31119478, -0.68396461, -0.65981078], [ 0.65285712, -0.07680383, -0.75357729], [ 0.71209121, -0.26699486,  0.64933801], [ 0.97685069, -0.17835225,  0.11812361], [-0.34381351, -0.93718553, -0.05895334], [ 0.68615079, -0.67022949,  0.2828241 ], [-0.6588605 , -0.59295917, -0.46292791], [ 0.15754543, -0.46902952, -0.86901712], [ 0.89081973, -0.0551779 ,  0.45099396], [ 0.09939465, -0.40802586,  0.90754372], [ 0.93604255, -0.26702261, -0.22917943], [-0.93707269, -0.34256476,  0.06741077], [-0.19623031, -0.95031369,  0.24165596], [ 0.45153776, -0.87650371,  0.16689767], [-0.0195914 , -0.72917062, -0.68405145], [ 0.65216494, -0.75583613, -0.05824633], [ 0.13336134, -0.97014433,  0.20257032], [ 0.86954373, -0.49204889,  0.04220884], [ 0.60317737, -0.57162017, -0.55626202], [-0.34353963, -0.78447777,  0.51630914], [-0.35424244, -0.68266952, -0.63912022], [-0.84101379, -0.50332689, -0.19838808], [-0.85885382, -0.33475134,  0.38770047], [ 0.30507854, -0.94518369, -0.11642545], [ 0.7822451 , -0.55481136, -0.28333196], [-0.15034926, -0.90096235, -0.4070158 ], [-0.37529847, -0.20644124, -0.90362221], [-0.87414831, -0.01486413,  0.48543158]])
u, v, w = gradients.T

# Put cones on the outside of the sphere
for direct in [-1, 1]:
    h = direct * 0.2 # Head length
    mlab.quiver3d(direct*u, direct*v, direct*w, h*u, h*v, h*w, color=(.2,.2,.2),
                  mode='cone', scale_factor=1, resolution=20)

mlab.show()
```

[image]

You could also make the sphere slightly larger as a fudge factor to get around the flat sides not exactly intersecting the base of some cones (e.g. `points3d([0],[0],[0],[2.05],...)`):

[image]

Another way to show this is a stereonet.  Stereonets are a bit obscure, but they're a very good way to show distribution of orientations in 3D using a 2D plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplstereonet

gradients = np.array([[ 0.57735027, -0.57735027,  0.57735027], [ 0.32103634, -0.15367924, -0.93451506], [ 0.41923004, -0.40336058,  0.81335509], [ 0.49175236, -0.7972576 , -0.35008559], [-0.77544582, -0.60942662,  0.16517574], [ 0.49080035, -0.37864643, -0.78469223], [-0.9688558 , -0.14921457, -0.19761968], [-0.55381966, -0.41340241, -0.72276008], [-0.51651138, -0.82581121,  0.22638878], [ 0.51285124, -0.09350922,  0.85336959], [-0.02404559, -0.99431705, -0.10370783], [-0.45752126, -0.15967038,  0.87474549], [-0.11906644, -0.66461051,  0.73764223], [-0.69553846, -0.26904184,  0.66621518], [ 0.84464198, -0.38759068,  0.3692607 ], [ 0.01218729, -0.86413401,  0.5031141 ], [-0.70542359, -0.10816363, -0.70048422], [-0.64579558, -0.75719821, -0.09797404], [ 0.22307518, -0.66173422,  0.715783  ], [ 0.35672677, -0.81123132,  0.46330312], [-0.64859039, -0.59819001,  0.47063699], [-0.9860335 , -0.04110239,  0.16139577], [ 0.78665483, -0.298026  , -0.54069835], [-0.22515292, -0.39356178,  0.89129978], [-0.03115982, -0.20828982, -0.97757065], [ 0.1714755 , -0.88971114, -0.42309603], [-0.1948448 , -0.48424336, -0.85296184], [-0.46394941, -0.51801461,  0.71861798], [-0.45273268, -0.81954175, -0.35126126], [-0.82887799, -0.29984823, -0.47228414], [ 0.21121763, -0.09845807,  0.97246754], [-0.11702234, -0.10076906,  0.98800373], [ 0.31119478, -0.68396461, -0.65981078], [ 0.65285712, -0.07680383, -0.75357729], [ 0.71209121, -0.26699486,  0.64933801], [ 0.97685069, -0.17835225,  0.11812361], [-0.34381351, -0.93718553, -0.05895334], [ 0.68615079, -0.67022949,  0.2828241 ], [-0.6588605 , -0.59295917, -0.46292791], [ 0.15754543, -0.46902952, -0.86901712], [ 0.89081973, -0.0551779 ,  0.45099396], [ 0.09939465, -0.40802586,  0.90754372], [ 0.93604255, -0.26702261, -0.22917943], [-0.93707269, -0.34256476,  0.06741077], [-0.19623031, -0.95031369,  0.24165596], [ 0.45153776, -0.87650371,  0.16689767], [-0.0195914 , -0.72917062, -0.68405145], [ 0.65216494, -0.75583613, -0.05824633], [ 0.13336134, -0.97014433,  0.20257032], [ 0.86954373, -0.49204889,  0.04220884], [ 0.60317737, -0.57162017, -0.55626202], [-0.34353963, -0.78447777,  0.51630914], [-0.35424244, -0.68266952, -0.63912022], [-0.84101379, -0.50332689, -0.19838808], [-0.85885382, -0.33475134,  0.38770047], [ 0.30507854, -0.94518369, -0.11642545], [ 0.7822451 , -0.55481136, -0.28333196], [-0.15034926, -0.90096235, -0.4070158 ], [-0.37529847, -0.20644124, -0.90362221], [-0.87414831, -0.01486413,  0.48543158]])
x, y, z = gradients.T

fig, ax = mplstereonet.subplots(projection='equal_area')
ax.grid(True)
ax.pole(*mplstereonet.vector2pole(x,y,z))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Speechless. Wonderful. I would upvote a thousand times! (wait, thats almost more than the half of my score.) You helped me so much. I really prefer the idea to not render the interior, but shading the gray surface! I just modified it a bit, to let the arrow heads plus a little of the tube stay on top of the surface. Again: wonderful + thanks!

Comment: I'm doing something similar (well, using quiver3d at least). Is there an easy way to fix the size of the arrow head and shaft diameter but allow the length of the shaft to scale? ..I guess this is along the lines of your "custom glyph" suggestion. (I've started reading a bit about the details of mayavi/tvtk pipelines/sources etc. but it seems a bit overkill to go down that route for such a small request.)

Comment: @dan-man - That's effectively what the second example in my answer does.  Unfortunately, there's not a significantly better way to do it, as far as I know.  The "custom glyph" I mentioned would still be static. The head and shaft of the arrow would have to have a fixed ratio that couldn't change with the data. (It would work for this case because the arrows are all the same length.) In VTK, you can scale a glyph by a scalar, but the _entire_ glyph has to scale, so the shaft of the arrow can't be independent unless they're two separate objects.

Comment: @JoeKington - thanks. I clearly wasn't very thorough with my first reading of your post...but it is a bit surprising that there's no simple way to draw a "regular" arrow of the kind you find in most basic 2d settings...matplotlib/MSword etc.